# why is jasmine-node not picking up my helper script?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, node.js, jasmine

This question is likely based in my lack of previous experience with node.js, but I was hoping jasmine-node would just let me run my jasmine specs from the command line.

TestHelper.js:

```
var helper_func = function() {
    console.log("IN HELPER FUNC");
};
```

my_test.spec.js:

```
describe ('Example Test', function() {
  it ('should use the helper function', function() {
    helper_func();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }); 
});
```

Those are the only two files in the directory. Then, when I do:

```
jasmine-node .
```

I get

```
ReferenceError: helper_func is not defined
```

I'm sure the answer to this is easy, but I didn't find any super-simple intros, or anything obvious on github. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In node, everything is namespaced to it's js file. To make the function callable by other files, change TestHelper.js to look like this:

```
var helper_func = function() {
    console.log("IN HELPER FUNC");
};
// exports is the "magic" variable that other files can read
exports.helper_func = helper_func;
```

And then change your my_test.spec.js to look like this:

```
// include the helpers and get a reference to it's exports variable
var helpers = require('./TestHelpers');

describe ('Example Test', function() {
  it ('should use the helper function', function() {
    helpers.helper_func(); // note the change here too
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }); 
});
```

and, lastly, I believe `jasmine-node .` will run every file in the directory sequentially - but you don't need to run the helpers. Instead you could move them to a different directory (and change the `./` in the `require()` to the correct path), or you could just run `jasmine-node *.spec.js`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So...to be greedy, can this somehow be converted to run on jasmine-node AND using SpecRunner.html? When using the html version, I get "exports is not defined" and "require is not defined".

Comment: Alternatively, you can just do something if(require){...[load files]...}` and `if(!exports) { var exports = window.helpers = {} }` for a simple solution

Comment: I've been searching for this answer whole day. I didn't want to use Ruby with Jasmine. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Jasmine works fine with node.js without jasmine-node. Though it prefers `module.exports`.

Comment: Yea, that's true now. I don't think it was the case 2+ years ago though.

Answer (score 4):

you do not necessarily need to include your helper script in the spec (testing) file if you have the jasmine config as:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

Everything in the helpers/ folder will run before the Spec files. In the helpers files have something like this to include your function.

```
beforeAll(function(){
  this.helper_func = function() {
  console.log("IN HELPER FUNC");
  };
});
```

you will then be able to make references to it in your spec files

Comment: I was wondering what the `helpers` actually are and how to use them. I used to use `module.exports` and `require` for utils files before. The Jasmine docs show only how to set the helpers paths in the config files. Thank you for that clarifications, helpers seem to be very.. helpful :)